# R: how to set the extent of a map which is in Lambert projection?

Tags: r

I would like to plot a map which is a bathy object obtained from the marmap package.  I transformed the projection into a Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection in order to plot long distance flight movements. I simply used plot() to do so and it worked fine.

```
# Get data -> raster world map (bathymetry map)
world <- getNOAA.bathy(-180, 180, -90, 90, res = 15, keep = TRUE)

# Switch to raster
world.ras <- as.raster(world)

# Set the projection to Lambert Azimuthal Eqaul Area and project
my.proj <- "+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=-30 +lat_0=40+ellps=GRS80"
world.ras.proj <- projectRaster(world.ras,crs = my.proj)

# Switch back to a bathy object
world.proj <- as.bathy(world.ras.proj)

# Set colors for oceans and land masses
blues <- c("lightsteelblue4", "lightsteelblue3",
           "lightsteelblue2", "lightsteelblue1")
greys <- c(grey(0.6), grey(0.93), grey(0.99))

#plot map
plot(world.proj, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, 
     lwd = 0.01,
     bpal = list(c(0, max(world.proj, na.rm = T), greys),
                 c(min(world.proj, na.rm = T), 0, blues)),
     deep = 0,
     shallow = 0,
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
plot(world.proj, n = 1,
     lwd=0.8,
     col="grey",
     add = TRUE)
```

However, I don't know how to set the extent of the final map (to crop it). Of course, if I simply import a map with the extent a want (see below), when I transform the projection into Lambert I end up with a conical map.

```
map <- getNOAA.bathy(-80, 10, 0, 80, res = 25, keep = TRUE)
```

My question: how can I get a final rectangular map that will include all the area I need (xlim = -80, 10 and ylim = 80, 0)?

Additionally: I will also need to add a graticule every 20 degree of lat/lon.

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that when you project `world`, the original coordinate system (in decimal degrees) is replaced by a new coordinate system. You can visualise this by adding the axes to your plot:

```
# Plot bathymetric/hypsometric map
plot(world.proj, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.01,
     bpal = list(c(0, max(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), greys),
                 c(min(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), 0, blues)),
     deep = 0, shallow = 0,
     axes = TRUE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
# Add coastline
plot(world.proj, n = 1, lwd = 0.3, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

In order to zoom on the area you're interested in (-80 to 10 degrees longitude and 0 to 80 degrees latitude), you need to project the coordinates of the corner of this area, expressed in degrees into the same projection you used for the map:

```
# Projection of the coordinates of the corners of the area of interest
corners <- data.frame(lon = c(-80, -80, 10, 10, -80), lat = c(0, 80, 80, 0, 0))
corners.proj <- project(as.matrix(corners), proj = my.proj)
lines(corners.proj, col = 2)
```

[image]

All you have to do now is use `xlim` and `ylim` to zoom on a rectangle covering the area of interest:

```
# Plot bathymetric/hypsometric map
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(world.proj, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.01,
     bpal = list(c(0, max(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), greys),
                 c(min(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), 0, blues)),
     deep = 0, shallow = 0,
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
     xlim = range(corners.proj[,1]), 
     ylim = range(corners.proj[,2]))
# Add coastline
plot(world.proj, n = 1, lwd = 0.3, add = TRUE)

# Highlight the area of interest for reference
lines(corners.proj, col = 2)
```

[image]

Finally, graticules need to be projected as well in order to appear on the projected map. The `graticule` package provides all the tools needed:

```
# Plot bathymetric/hypsometric map
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0)
plot(world.proj, image = TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.01,
     bpal = list(c(0, max(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), greys),
                 c(min(world.proj, na.rm = TRUE), 0, blues)),
     deep = 0, shallow = 0,
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "",
     xlim = range(corners.proj[,1]), 
     ylim = range(corners.proj[,2]))
# Add coastline
plot(world.proj, n = 1, lwd = 0.3, add = TRUE)

library(graticule)

## specify where you want meridians and parallels
lons <- seq(-180, 180, by = 20)
lats <- seq(0, 80, by = 20)

## build the (projected graticules) lines
grat <- graticule(lons, lats, proj = my.proj)

## Add graticules to the plot
plot(grat, add = TRUE, lty = 5)
```

[image]

The [graticule vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graticule/vignettes/graticule.html) has many other examples.

Comment: I realized I did not thank you yet, Benoit. Your detailed answer was very helpful!!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answers your question, could you please accept it?